# Javascript keeps a div hidden until you click a button, need help modifying

Tags: javascript, html, hide

Basically, my code right now keeps a few of the divs I have on my website hidden and then when you click on a link, it makes the divs appear.

I need help so that it so that when I click one link and a div appears and I click on another link, the previous one disappears.

So let's say I click the link 'About', the div appears, good. Then I click on 'Help' and that div just appears OVER 'About' making things messy.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function unhide(divID) {
var item = document.getElementById(divID);
if (item) {
item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
}}
</script>
```

^That is my code, here is a sample of it in my website:

```
    <div id="about" class="hidden">
    <div class="content3">
        <p>This is the about section.</p>
        <p>It is currently still being worked on.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

The class 'content3' is just styling in my css file.

```
.content3 {
background-color:#FFFFFF;
width:750px;
height:600px;
padding:5px;
padding-left:40px;
margin-top:-650px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

UPDATE:

Sorry, I should elaborate more..
I need to be able to basically click a first link and have it show a box of text.

and then click a second link that will hide that box of text associated with the first link and show a new one that is associated with the second link.

This is my FULL code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function unhide(divID) {
    var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (item) {
    item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
    }}
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="title">
        <p class="text_header">Benjamin Midyette</p>
        <p style="margin-top:-50px">Computer/Network Engineer, Web Developer</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content" align="left">
        <p style="padding-top:20px">
            <a href="javascript:unhide('link')" class="button">This is a link</a><br><br>
            <a href="javascript:unhide('about')" class="button">About</a>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="Resume" class="content2"></div>

    <div id="link" class="hidden" style="position:absolute; left:300px; margin-top:-700px;">
            <img alt="A Link" src="pictures/link.png" height="420" width="420">     
    </div>

    <div id="about" class="hidden">
        <div class="content3">
            <p>This is the about section.</p>
            <p>It is currently still being worked on.</p>
        </div>
    </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image:url('http://www.nsgaming.us/pictures/nebula.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background: url('http://www.nsgaming.us/pictures/nebula.png') fixed 100% 100%;}

/*Text styling*/
.text_header {
    font-size:72px
    }

.title {
    margin-top:-30px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align: center;
    color:#ffffee;
    width:600px;
    border-radius:8px;
    background-color:#000000;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.9);
    padding-bottom:1px;
    }

/*Top Button styling*/
.button {
    border:2px solid black;
    background: #3B3B3B; /*#8C8C8C*/
    padding: 3.5px 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
.button:hover {
    background: #770819;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;}
.button:active {
    background: #590819;}

.content {
    margin-top:40px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius:8px;
    Opacity:0.8;
    background:#222222;
    width:175px;
    height:400px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-top: 0px;}

.content2 {
    background-color:#222222;
    border-radius:4px;
    width:800px;
    height:650px;
    padding:5px;
    padding-left:40px;
    margin-top:-401px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    }

.content3 {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    width:750px;
    height:600px;
    padding:5px;
    padding-left:40px;
    margin-top:-635px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    }

.hidden { 
    display: none; }

.unhidden { 
    display: block; }

container {
    align:right;}
opener {
    align:left;}
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, you want display div on paticular click of a button and hide that appeared div on click of other button.?

Comment: Yes, I tried reversing it by taking 'unhidden' to 'hidden and 'unhidden' (basically the opposite of the 3rd to last line of code in the first code box) but it didn't work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do like this, if you want to display and hide particular div on click of button.

```
<style>
.hidden{
    display:none;
}

.unhidden{
    display:block;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function unhide(clickedButton, divID) {
var item = document.getElementById(divID);
if (item) {
    if(item.className=='hidden'){
        item.className = 'unhidden' ;
        clickedButton.value = 'hide'
    }else{
        item.className = 'hidden';
        clickedButton.value = 'unhide'
    }
}}

</script>

<body>
<div id="about" class="hidden">
<div class="content3">
<p>This is the about section.</p>
<p>It is currently still being worked on.</p>
</div>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="unhide(this, 'about') " value="unhide">
</body>
```

**UPDATE:** Pass the other div id which you want to make disappear on click of div one. Please update your code with below's code.

SCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function unhide(divID, otherDivId) {
    var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (item) {
            item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
        }
        document.getElementById(otherDivId).className = 'hidden';
    }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<p style="padding-top:20px">
    <a href="javascript:unhide('link', 'about')" class="button">This is a link</a><br><br>
    <a href="javascript:unhide('about', 'link')" class="button">About</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing, I updated my original post to make it clear what I was kind of looking for, sorry it was unclear.

Comment: Thanks so much! It works perfectly! For the future, if I want to add a 3rd link, would I just add it to the links in the "javascript:unhide('') tag? Like if I were to add a page called say 'Music', I would have 3 links, each of them containing ('link', 'about', 'music'?

Comment: In that case, you will have to pass third div id with `unhide('link', 'about', 'music')'`, and inside the `unhide()` function   you need to add, `document.getElementById(thirdId).className = 'hidden';` thirdId is getting as parameter with  `function unhide(divID, otherDivId, thirdId)`, But if you want more links/divs, good practice would be, get all the divs(which would be disappear) by className and make it disappear.

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand your question properly. But if you are trying to make different `div` elements visible upon clicking different links, then this is what you should do:

```
<div id = "anchor-div">
      <ul>
        <li> <a id="about-anchor" href="javascript:;"> About</a> </li> 
        <li> <a id="help-anchor" href="javascript:;"> Help </a> </li>
      </ul>
</div>


<div id="content-div">
       <div id="about-content"></div>
       <div id="help-content"></div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        //if you wish to keep both the divs hidden by default then dont forget to hide //them           
        $("#help-content").hide();
        $("#about-content").hide();

       $("#about-anchor").click(function(){
             $("#help-content").hide();
             $("#about-content").show();
        });

      $("#help-anchor").click(function(){
              $("#help-content").show();
             $("#about-content").hide();
       });
});
```

Also don't forget to add jQuery library.