# Display Item from Dropdown of Options with JavaScript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, html

I have constructed an HTML page along with some CSS. I have placed a button that provides a dropdown of several meetings. Each time you click on each one of the meetingsin this dropdown, I'd like for a headline and a set of text to appear that provide info on what happened at this meeting. The following is the code

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Meeting Types</title>
    <style>
        #meetings div {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <h1>Meetings Types</h1>

    <div id="meetings">

        <form id="myForm">
            <select id="gatherings">
                <option value="" selected>Choose a Meeting</option>
                <option value="meeting-a">Meeting A</option>
                <option value="meeting-b">Meeting B</option>
                <option value="meeting-c">Meeting C</option>
            </select>

        </form>

        <p><button id="showAll">Show All Meetings</button></p>

        <div id="meeting-a">
            <h2>Meeting A</h2>
            <p>This meeting occured in district 10 with members of district of 12 with lots of input from 
            many different individuals.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="meeting-b">
            <h2>Meeting B</h2>
            <p>This meeting occured in district 34 with members of 54 presiding.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="meeting-c">
            <h2>Meeting C</h2>
            <p>This meeting occured in district 4 with members of district 45 presiding with input.</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to construct JavaScript or Jquery so that when I select a meeting from the "Choose a Meeting Dropdown" below I see the heading (what's in between the `<h2>` tag) and what I wrote in between the `<p>` tags. Additionally, when I click on the button "Show All Meeting", then all the information appears at once (i.e. a heading of Meeting A and the corresponding paragraph describing what happened in it, the heading for Meeting B and what happened in it, the heading for Meeting C, and what happened in it.

I have used several stackoverflow threads to attempt to answer this question. One such thread led me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26281155/jquery-functions-one-to-display-dropdown-on-click-and-another-to-get-selected-i). And still another led me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494924/javascript-keeps-a-div-hidden-until-you-click-a-button-need-help-modifying). The most useful thing has been this w3school [lesson](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown) which is very similar to what I'm trying to accomplish but doesn't quite permit me to display the material within the H2 nodes and p nodes within my original file. I think jquery may be the most effective way to do this but Javascript might be applicable as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some jquery you can achieve this,you can use jquery `hide` and `show` methods to hide and show corresponding divs and change event for tracking drop down selection change:

```
$("#showAll").click(function(){
   $(".my-meeting").show();
});

$("#gatherings").change(function(){

    var valueSelected = this.value;
    $(".my-meeting").hide();
    $("#" + valueSelected).show();
});
```

I also added `.my-meeting` class to meeting divs for selecting and hiding all divs.

I think you are looking for something like **[This](https://jsfiddle.net/hsh85/pp7p6nq4/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You need onchange function of `dropdown` to show respective meeting. Assign a `class` to every meeting `div` so it can be accessed through class for showing hiding `divs`.

On page load hide all `divs` and when user selects a value from dropdown show respective `div`.

Also make your button `type="button` because currently your `button` is `submitting` 
the `page`
Below is a complete solution for this

**HTML**

```
<div id="meetings">


            <select id="gatherings" onchange="ShowSelectedMeeting()">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Choose a Meeting</option>
                <option value="meeting-a">Meeting A</option>
                <option value="meeting-b">Meeting B</option>
                <option value="meeting-c">Meeting C</option>
            </select>



        <p><button type="button" id="showAll" onclick="ShowAll()">Show All Meetings</button></p>

        <div id="meeting-a" class="meeting">
            <h2>Meeting A</h2>
            <p>This meeting occured in district 10 with members of district of 12 with lots of input from 
            many different individuals.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="meeting-b" class="meeting">
            <h2>Meeting B</h2>
            <p>This meeting occured in district 34 with members of 54 presiding.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="meeting-c" class="meeting">
            <h2>Meeting C</h2>
            <p>This meeting occured in district 4 with members of district 45 presiding with input.</p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
        $(function () {

            $('.meeting').hide();

        });
        function ShowSelectedMeeting()
        {

            var Id = $("#gatherings").val();
            $('.meeting').hide();//To hide other meeting div so only one show at a time
            $("#"+Id).show();
        }

        function ShowAll()
        {
            $('.meeting').show();
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript:

```
var slt = document.getElementById("gatherings");
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("meeting");
slt.addEventListener("change", function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    var elemId = slt.options[slt.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById(elemId).style.display = "block";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <select id="gatherings" onchange="ShowSelectedMeeting()">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Choose a Meeting</option>
            <option value="meeting-a">Meeting A</option>
            <option value="meeting-b">Meeting B</option>
            <option value="meeting-c">Meeting C</option>
        </select>



    <p><button type="button" id="showAll" onclick="ShowAll()">Show All Meetings</button></p>

    <div id="meeting-a" class="meeting">
        <h2>Meeting A</h2>
        <p>This meeting occured in district 10 with members of district of 12 with lots of input from 
        many different individuals.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="meeting-b" class="meeting">
        <h2>Meeting B</h2>
        <p>This meeting occured in district 34 with members of 54 presiding.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="meeting-c" class="meeting">
        <h2>Meeting C</h2>
        <p>This meeting occured in district 4 with members of district 45 presiding with input.</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

$(function () {

            $('.meeting').hide();

        });


 


 

        function ShowSelectedMeeting()
        {

            var Id = $("#gatherings").val();
            $('.meeting').hide();//To hide other meeting div so only one show at a time
            $("#"+Id).show();
        }

        function ShowAll()
        {
            $('.meeting').show();
        }